Interpreting the plot for sensitivity analysis for mediation analysis using the mediation package
I have performed a mediation analysis using the mediation package for R and the recommended sensitivity analysis. Despite reading "Identification, Inference, and Sensitivity Analysis for Causal Mediation Effects" by Imai et al., I am having difficulty understanding how to interpret the results of the sensitivity analysis. Does the attached plot indicate a low or high probability of failure to meet the assumptions of the mediation analysis?


I think the gray shaded region represents the confidence interval for Average Causal Mediation Effect across different values of the sensitivity parameter. If the confidence interval crosses zero (as it does here), this indicates that the mediation effect could be non-significant (at certain levels)

Confidence interval always crosses zero on Rho axis, because ACME is calculated for values of Rho between -1 and 1. It never crosses 0 on ACME axis on this plot. According to Imai at al: "The horizontal dashed line is drawn at the point estimate of ¯ δ under Assumption 1." It does not represent 0. So I'm not sure if your interpretation is correct.

EDIT: It crosses only in top right quarter.
